# Construct a vector of names from data frame using R

Tags: r, vector

I have a big data frame that contains data about the outcomes of sports matches. I want to try and extract specific data from the data frame depending on certain criteria. Here's a quick example of what I mean...
Imagine I have a data frame df, which displays data about specific football matches of a tournament on each row, like so:

```
   Winner_Teams Win_Capt_Nm Win_Country Loser_teams Lose_Capt_Nm Lose_Country
1      Man utd        John     England   Barcalona       Carlos        Spain
2    Liverpool       Steve     England    Juventus        Mario        Italy
3      Man utd        John    Scotland    R Madrid         Juan        Spain
4     Paris SG      Teirey      France     Chelsea         Mark      England
```

So, for example,  in row [1] Man utd won against Barcalona, Man utd's captain's name was John and he is from England. Barcalona's (the losers of the match) captain's name was Carlos and he is from Spain.

I want to construct a vector with the names of all English players in the tournament, where the output should look something like this:

```
[1] "John"  "Mark"  "Steve"
```

Here's what I've tried so far... 
My first step was to create a data frame that discards all the matches that don't have English captains

```
> England_player <- data.frame(filter(df, Win_Country=="England" ))
> England_player

 Winner_Teams Win_Capt_Nm Win_Country Loser_teams Lose_Capt_Nm Lose_Country
1      Man utd        John     England   Barcalona       Carlos        Spain
2    Liverpool       Steve     England    Juventus        Mario        Italy
3     Paris SG      Teirey      France     Chelsea         MArk      England
```

Then I used select() on England_player to isolate just the names:

```
> England_player_names <- select(England_player, Win_Capt_Nm, Lose_Capt_Nm)
> England_player_names

  Win_Capt_Nm Lose_Capt_Nm
1        John       Carlos
2       Steve        Mario
3      Teirey         Mark
```

And then I get stuck! As you can see, the output displays the English winner's name and the name of his opponent... which is not what I want!
It's easy to just read the names off this data frame.. but the data frame I'm working with is large, so just reading the values is no good!
Any suggestions as to how I'd do this?

Comment: Seems like you need to combine two subsets - the `Win_Capt_Nm` when `Win_Country` is England, and the `Lose_Cpt_Nm` when the `Lose_Country` is England. Pull each vector separately, use `c()` to combine them.

Comment: This is otherwise a good question but please remember to share your data via `dput()` when using the R tag. Hover your pointer over the `r` tag for more info.

Comment: I think you need to make two subsets: first you subset on win country = england and get names of players.  Then you subset on lose country = England and do the same.  Finally you put the two lists together by rbind,.  This can however lead to duplicates,  which yoi can remove with 'uniq'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
english.players <- union(data$Win_Capt_Nm[data$Win_Country == 'England'], data$Lose_Capt_Nm[data$Lose_Country == 'England'])

[1] "John"  "Steve" "Mark"
```

Comment: This is perfect! I've only just discovered the union() command and already I love it! Thanks!

Comment: Note that the use of `union` will remove any duplicated names. To keep duplicates, do `c()` instead of `union()`.